# Can't access chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() when creating actual popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension, with a `content-script.js`, a `background.js`, and a `popup.html`. It runs a sentiment analysis on editable areas like `#textarea`.

To communicate between the `content-script.js` and the `background.js`, I'm using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message)`, and running the analyses on `background.js` and saving the results to `window.text`. If there is a negative sentiment, I send a message back to the page to show an image of a stop sign.

Then on the `popup.html` (which is really a `.vue` file), so

```
mounted(){
this.bgpage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
this.text = this.bgpage.text
}
```

and displaying the `{{text}}` in the template.

It worked perfectly. But I didn't love that users would have to click the button on the `browser_action` to engage with the popup.

So I added this listener and function to the `content-script.js`:

```
document.addEventListener("click", clickStop)
function clickStop(event) {

  let target = event.target.getAttribute('id');
  if (target == "stop"){
  let message = {
    stop: true
  }
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message)
  }
```

and this to the `background.js`

```
function receiver(request) { 
if (request.stop == true){
    window.open("popup.html", "default_title", "width=375,height=600,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,top=0,left=0");
  }
```

and this works as well. Now I have a popup when a user clicks on the stop sign.

The problem is that it seems that the new popup window doesn't access the `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, which means that the `{{text}}` doesn't show up, like it would if the user would click on the actual `browser_action` button. (`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` crashes everything for some reason.)

I've added the permissions for background to to the `manifest.json`:

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "background"
  ],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent" : true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "default_popup",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/stopsign.png",
      "38": "icons/stopsign.png"
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to get the literal new popup window to work just like the `browser_action`.

Comment: The problem is that with `"persistent": false` your background page is loaded only a) when an API event occurs and b) when the built-in browser_action or page_action is opened. So since your popup.html is a normal window the background page will unload automatically and break your code. See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](/a/54715122). You can also prevent the background page from unloading by [opening a port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect).

Comment: Changed to `"persistent": true`. Problem still stands.

Comment: You need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json.

Comment: I literally uninstalled and reinstalled it. (and edited code in question to reflect this)

Comment: This should work normally and works in other extensions so it looks like there's a bug in the browser or something else is at play. Anyway, sharing data via the background page isn't the only solution, see the answer I've linked above. Also try creating the window via chrome.windows.create instead of window.open.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in a part of the code that I didn't share, because I hadn't thought it was relevant, and I was wrong.

Basically, I had two different `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);` on my `content-script.js`: one had an `if` statement on the `receiver` and the other did not. So every time I sent the `request.stop` message, the `request.text` was `undefined` and therefore caused `window.text` to become `undefined`.

Therefore, it worked on my `browser-action` popup, because there was no `request.stop` message sent, so `window.text` was still defined by the last message.

Once I added the second conditional statement, that would not run when the `request.stop` message was received.

```
window.text = "there is no text";

function receiver(request) {
if (request.stop == true){
  window.open("popup.html", "default_title", "width=375,height=600,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,top=0,left=0");
}

//removed this
//window.text = request.text;

//added this - if statement
if (request.text){
  window.text = request.text;
}
}
```